# Objective C NSMutableURLRequest GET request returns null JSON

Tags: objective-c, json, get, nsjsonserialization, nsmutableurlrequest

trying **get Data from server using @"GET" request**,
this following code **returns null** all time:

is anybody finding an issue with my following code?

or it's can be server side Issue..
?

**thank for your help!**

```
+ (id)sendParam:(NSString*)ParamString url:(NSString*)url{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];


    NSString *post = ParamString;

    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];

    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];


    NSLog(@"postLength =%@",postLength);

    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request addValue:ParamString forHTTPHeaderField:@"GET"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error;

    NSData *aData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    NSMutableArray*jsonReturn = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    jsonReturn = (NSMutableArray*)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:aData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSLog(@"jsonReturn %@",jsonReturn);

    return jsonReturn;
}
```

after Editing:

```
  + (id)sendParam:(NSString*)ParamString url:(NSString*)url{

    NSString*StringGETMETHOD = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",url,ParamString];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:StringGETMETHOD]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];


    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error;

    NSData *aData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSLog(@"aData=%@",aData);


    if (aData) {

        jsonReturn=(NSMutableArray*)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:aData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

        NSLog(@"jsonReturn %@",jsonReturn);


}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use GET for getting response from server just you can try in following method

```
//just give your URL instead of my URL
NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL  URLWithString:@"http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/search.ashx?query=London&num_of_results=3&format=json&key=xkq544hkar4m69qujdgujn7w"]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

[request setValue:@"application/json;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];

NSError *err;

NSURLResponse *response;

NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request   returningResponse:&response error:&err];

 //You need to check response.Once you get the response copy that and paste in ONLINE JSON VIEWER.If you do this clearly you can get the correct results.    

 //After that it depends upon the json format whether it is DICTIONARY or ARRAY 

NSDictionary *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &err];

NSArray *array=[[jsonArray objectForKey:@"search_api"]objectForKey:@"result"];
```

Answer (score 1):

I very much doubt that you should send this parameter as a HEADER field. 
I also would think that you should be sending a POST and not a GET.

Setting jsonReturn to [[NSMutableArray alloc] init] is nonsense. Explain to yourself why you are doing it instead of setting jsonReturn to nil

Logging the jsonReturn is nonsense, because all the interesting stuff has disappeared. You should log the response and the data that was returned, at least if jsonReturn = nil.

Comment: You mean that the log should show `aData` and `error` (both before and after the JSON deserialization), yes?

Comment: If jsonReturn is not nil, then you know the http request was just fine, so no need to log it. If jsonReturn is nil, you want to know whether the problem was with http or with the data that was returned, so you probably want to log the error, the response, and the data. You need to log both error and response, because "error" is about communication with the server, while "response" is about what the server decided to do. If the server says "you can't have the data you asked for", that's no error as far as the http request is concerned; it told you what the server said, so it's no error.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confused between GET and POST. You are doing a GET, but supplying data like a POST (usually does, though it isn't mandated, or precluded to use the body data for a GET).

Generally, you don't want to use body data for a GET, it isn't usual / expected so any number of different issues could be occurring. Either change `setHTTPMethod:` to `@"POST"` so you are doing a POST properly, or change the parameters to be part of the request URL.

It really all depends what the server expects (and can handle). This is what you need to know and match against...

---

Subsequently you have a different issue. The param string you supply has characters in it that need to be encoded (like spaces). Use `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` on the param string before you send it to escape these characters.

It works in a browser because it is adding the escape characters for you (which you should see in the browser address bar after it has loaded the response).

Comment: so you mean that i can use HTTPMethod @"POST", and Server Side that using "GET" Method can Handle it ?

Thanks Wain for your response..

Comment: No, if the server expects get and not post then you should send a GET but with the parameters encoded as part of the URL, not in the body data. Do you have a log of errors on the server to tell you what it thinks is wrong?

Comment: Hi Wain 
please see my Editing Code Above..
is that seems ok?
(still returns null),

 but copying `"POST" string` to the browser, returns results.

Comment: Change `[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];` to `[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];`. The answer from @user3182143 is a good overview of the code you should have.

Comment: its still Strange,
if i Copy Pasting The URL + Param String on the browser, it returns results..

but build request from IOS side like user3182143's Code, returns null..



`http://81.218.79.240/apns/apns.php?task=fetchgames&user_uid=502122107&search_epoc=2014-02-17 12:23:03 +0000&user_city=tel aviv&user_latitude=0.000000&user_longitude=0.000000`

Answer (score 0):

i found my issue:

sending paramString Using "Get" Method, cannot send parameters with space between letters.. example: "tel aviv" should be "tel%20aviv"

by adding the following code line:

```
 **urlParam = [urlParam
                  stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];**
```

fix code:

```
 + (id)sendParam:(NSString*)ParamString url:(NSString*)url{

    NSString* urlParam = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",url,ParamString];

 urlParam = [urlParam
                  stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];

  NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlParam]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    [request setValue:@"application/json;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];



    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error;

    NSData *aData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSLog(@"aData=%@",aData);


    if (aData) {

        jsonReturn=(NSMutableArray*)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:aData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

        NSLog(@"jsonReturn %@",jsonReturn);


}
```

thank you all !